# Popular a field of a schema with a schema that is inside an array (Moongose)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to obtain the data referring to the city_id which is a Schema, which is linked to an array of another Schema.

[This is the Schema called Companies and I need to get information about the city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYy8q.png)

```
{
"_id": "5fa1484a34a032ac5687b1c2",
"name": "Company",
"address": "Address",
"email": "email@email.com",
"phone": 123456789,
"city_id": "5fa147b607f466ac1d536bd0",
"__v": 0
```

},

Now, this is the City Schema. I have a Location Schema and this contains a Country relation:

```
import Country from './countrySchema';
const locationSchema = new Schema({
    region: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
       unique: true,
       dropDups: true
    },
    locations: [Country.schema]
},{ timestamps: true});

const locationModel = model("Location", locationSchema);
```

This is the Country Schema and this contains a City relation:

```
import City from './CitySchema';
const countrySchema = new Schema({
    country_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true
    },
    cities: [City.schema]
},{ _id: true, timestamps: true });

const countryModel = model("Country", countrySchema);
```

This is the City Schema:

```
const citySchema = new Schema({
    city_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true
    }
},{ _id: true, timestamps: true });

const cityModel = model("City", citySchema);
```

Finally, This looks like :

```
"_id": "5fa147b607f466ac1d536bce",
  "locations": [
    {
      "_id": "5fa147b607f466ac1d536bcf",
      "country_name": "Colombia",
      "cities": [
        {
          "_id": "5fa147b607f466ac1d536bd0",
          "city_name": "Medellín",
          "createdAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fa147b607f466ac1d536bd1",
          "city_name": "Bogotá",
          "createdAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z"
        }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-11-03T12:06:14.914Z"
    },
```

How can I get the city information?? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 locationModel.findOne({_id:"5fa147b607f466ac1d536bce"})
      .populate({ path:"locations",{path:"cities"}})
      .exec((err,location) => {
               if(err) reject(err);
               return resolve(location);   
            })`
```